# Chrome console can not access unused variable in lexical scope?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Let's say I have a function `foo`, and I set a break point in `console.log(c)`, and print `a` and `b` in chrome dev tool console. I can get `a` but I can not get `b`. I don't know why.

```
foo();

function foo(){
    var a = 2;
    var b = 3;
    bar(4);
    function bar(c) {
        console.log(a);
        // console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
    }
}
```

[image: console]

[image: Call Stack]

Comment: That's because `b` isn't used in the function, so v8 has already optimized the variable out of lookup by the time the debugger has reached the breakpoint

Comment: Yeah, it is frustrating.  If there's ever a variable in a higher scope I want to be able to inspect directly in my **Source** tab w/o having to use the **Scope** pane, I console log the values inside the intended scope-- this forces Chrome to keep them immediately available for inspection.  Goofy, but it works.